# Django_compressor hide the css?

Tags: css, django, compression

I am using  [django_compressor](https://github.com/mintchaos/django_compressor).

**In template :**

```
{% load compress %}
{% compress css %}
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/css/master.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
{% endcompress %}
```

**In settings :**

```
DEBUG = True
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'compressor',
     // Here other installed app.
]
```

But When I do these things my css is not getting uploaded. When I remove the `{% compress css %}` tag My css start rendreing. Where I am doing mess? Can any one suggest me?

Answer (score 0):

I would check two things:

1. if compress has access to the file itself
2. is generated file (e.g. under /media/cache/....) is accessible by browser

Answer (score 0):

In settings `COMPRESS` is a boolean that decides if compression will happen. Default value is the opposite of DEBUG. So you should change `DEBUG = True` to `DEBUG = False`.
(https://github.com/carljm/django_compressor)